# AppleScript: Create SmartInbox in Mail app from list

Tags: email, applescript

just wondering if you can help

I have set out to create Smart mailbox in Mail app using applescript
The list of emails for smart inbox are in myFile.txt on desktop. Each line has one email

I want to the smart Inbox with several emails, and want to automate it

I have tried the following script

```
tell application "Mail"
    activate
end tell

# GUI Script to initiate Smart Inbox creation

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Mail"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "Mailbox"
                tell menu "Mailbox"
                    click menu item "New Smart Mailbox…"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
        
        delay 1
        # Set name for the Smart Mailbox
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke ("MyAutomaticSmartMailBox" as text)

        keystroke tab

        # Set path to myFile.txt
        set srcFile to ((path to desktop) as text) & "myFile.txt"
        
        # Read lines from file.
        set lns to paragraphs of (read file srcFile as «class utf8»)
        
        # Loop over lines read and copy each to the clipboard.
        repeat with ln in lns
            set the clipboard to ln
            # Paste the clipboard into Smart inBox dialog
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke (the clipboard as text)
            # to create next line to add email
            click button "NSButtonCell"
        end repeat
        
        
    end tell
end tell
```

Gives me an error

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t make file \"MackintoshHD:Users:one:Desktop:myFile.txt\" of process \"Mail\" into type file." number -1700 from file "MackintoshHD:Users:one:Desktop:myFile.txt" of process "Mail" to file
```

Any help to resolve this error wud be appreciated
Also to change in drop down from "Any Recipient" to "From" in the Script
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`set theFile to ((path to desktop as text) & "test.txt")
```

set theData to paragraphs of (read file theFile)`
This shud read the file, set it up as List
then repeat with aData in the List
set rule
tell rule "a" to make new rule with condition at end of.....

This shud work :)